# Issue with .gitignore file and trying to run an app on heroku

Tags: javascript, github, heroku

I have a JS app - a newsletter signup form using mailchimp. It requires mailchimp api key and audience key which I had included in the app. I uploaded to github and that updates heroku and the app worked fine on heroku, briefly. Then mailchimp emailed me to say they had detected I had made api key public so disabled it. Git repository is public - guess I could make private as an option.

I figured I could put the keys into a config.json file and have the script get the info from there. Thats what I tried and put that filename into .gitignore so this would not go to github. However since heroku updates from github, it cant find the config.json file. If I dont put that file into .gitignore then the config.json file will be on github and again my api key will be public.

What should I be doing to keep api keys confidential while still being able to use github to update heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are [config variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)
After you added them you can load them just like any other environment variables.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to keep the api confidential but if I include it in a config file then thats not exactly confidential. First time I had it in the javascript code and Mailchimp picked it up so they are obviously crawling files looking for anything resembling an api key. For now I read that Heroku has an option to upload your secret stuff so I will look at that.  With great responsibility ...

Comment: Thanks. confidential data in .env,  .env listed in .gitignore, installed module dotenv and required this in code to grab env variables. Used Heroku config vars to substitute for those env vars. All works. Thanks again for pointing in the right direction.